# Eclipse formatter changing comment indentation

Tags: java, eclipse, comments, indentation, copy-paste

I've changed my eclipse formatter to using `Spaces Only` for indentation and an 'Indentation size' (and 'Tab size') of 2.

After making these changes, and no other changes from the built-in formatter, I now have a problem when pasting comments.

Instead of being indented correctly, for example:

```
  private String str1;
  // Correctly indented comment
  private String str2;
```

Now my comments are pasted in with no heading space and the space between the backslash and the comment text is removed, like so:

```
  private String str1;
//Incorrectly indented comment
  private String str2;
```

Is there some way to fix this behavior?

I have the `Adjust Indentation` property turned on under `Java -> Editor -> Typing -> When pasting`.

Installation details (from About):

> Eclipse SDK
>
> Version: 4.2.2
>
> Build id: M20130204-1200

Answer (score 0):

I think I could reproduce the problem that you are facing.

But it happens only if I copy from a source that is not indented. Is this your case?

Although I don’t have an explanation of why this happen, I think the fastest way to fix the indentation is to reapply the eclipse formatter to your code via Ctrl+A and then Ctrl+I.

The space between the backslash and the comment text still will not appear, but I hope it is not a big deal for you.

Comment: This happens when I copy the comment from a source that is indented. Also, in my case, applying Ctrl+I on the comment line does not fix the indentation. I can only fix it by also selecting the surrounding lines (or all as you suggest) but I don't always want to do that, for example when I apply some specific indentation. And as you mention, that does not fix the removed space and leads to very non-standard spacing.